# How do I String.Join a boxed array?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Given an `object` that may contain an array (e.g. `int[]`), how do I call the correct `IEnumerable<T>` `String.Join` overload?

```cs
var a = new []{1,2,3};
object o = a;

String.Join(",", a); // "1,2,3"
String.Join(",", o); // "System.Int32[]"
```

I would like the `String.Join` on `o` to be the array's contents, not the type name.

---

Full context and attempts below

I have an `object` that can contain anything, including various `IEnumerable<T>` and arrays e.g. `Int32[]`. I have a method that converts it to an appropriate string depending on the type:

```cs
private string ResultToString(object result)
{
    return result switch
    {
        string res => res,
        IEnumerable<object> enumerable => String.Join(", ", enumerable),
        null => "*null*",
        _ => result.ToString()
    };
}
```

Currently, if `result` is an `int[]`, it falls through to the default case.

- I can't cast the object to `IEnumerable<object>` or `object[]` because it's a value array
- I could cast the object to `IEnumerable<int>` but I don't know ahead of time that it is an `int`. I would like to avoid having to list a case for every value type (and wouldn't include structs?)
- I can cast the object to `IEnumerable` but that just calls the `object` overload of `String.Join` which results in an output of `System.Int32[]` -- there is unfortunately no `IEnumerable` overload, only `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to `IEnumerable` and then use [`Cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0%20#) which always succeeds with `Object`:

```
private string ResultToString(object result)
{
    IEnumerable enumerable = result as IEnumerable;
    if(enumerable == null) return result?.ToString();
    return string.Join(", ", enumerable.Cast<object>());
}
```

This calls [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) `String.Join` overload. Remarks:

> `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)` is a convenience method that lets you
> concatenate each member of an IEnumerable collection without first
> converting them to strings. The string representation of each object
> in the IEnumerable collection is derived by calling that object's
> ToString method.